# requestanimationframe slows down when publish

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I am building a game and i do the animations with requestanimationframe and when i run it locally on localhost everything goes smoothly and runs in the speed i want, but when i publish the game on github pages everything goes super slow. And I dont get any warning that the requestanimationframe took n secs to complete. Is it the speed of the server that the site is hosted on or should i check something else ?

The only thing i tried so far is increase the game speed but i didnt notice any changes in the final product

Comment: The `.requestAnimationFrame()` API has nothing at all to do with the server; it is purely a browser feature.

Comment: Does the fact that the hole website is a react app and the game is a route on it affect the speed ?

Comment: No. `.requestAnimationFrame()` asks the browser to schedule an operation the next time the client browser will have a redraw cycle available. It has nothing to do with React or the server or anything else. It is a native browser API.

Comment: Are there any AJAX requests while the game is playing?

Answer (score 0):

after some research i found out that the reason that it was slowing down was the frames, i did a performance log and found that i was getting partially prevented frame in some frames cause my screen was faster than 60fps, the way to fix that is to controll your frames in your requestanimationframe loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).